# FlowRouter Reload Doesn't Route

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm using FlowRouter. If I start on the homepage everything works well. I can work through the routes (change the pages) without problem. However, if I hit refresh in the browser, I get a series of errors. My url looks like this:

`/story/586d536e34821281735b53a4`

The ID is being returned in console under the following method:

`Tracker.nonreactive(function(){`

I think the subscription is being completed, so I'm a little confused as to why reloading a url is different than loading from the home page.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: What are the error messages you see exactly?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting:

```TypeError: Cannot read property 'audio' of undefined
    at story.js:121
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js?hash=9f8a0ce…:631)
    at Object.audios (story.js:111)
    at blaze.js?hash=983d07a…:2994
    at blaze.js?hash=983d07a…:1653
    at blaze.js?hash=983d07a…:3046
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=983d07a…:3687)
    ...```

What it translates into IMO is that mongo ```find``` is returning undefined because the subscription isn't being completed properly. But only on reload.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading a url will **make a HTTP request** to server to get all the application source. Whereas navigating to a route from another one **does not make any HTTP requests** to get the application source because they are already available (they were loaded from the previous route), in this case the router will just get the appropriate content and render on the page. This is normal behaviour for Meteor apps and all other single-page apps

The error you encounter is because your data is not yet available on client, to fix it you could simple use a placeholder if the value is `undefined`.